# Freeswitch verto performance is low

Tags: freeswitch

This is my first question, thanks in advance for all your help!
I setup a freeswitch server, and call it from a web page, I found freeswitch server costs more than 13 percent cpu, when it's idle it costs less than 1 percent, if I use a sip client call it, it costs about 4 percent cpu, anyone know why it costs 9 percent more cpu if use verto? Below is some detailed information.
Freeswitch version: 1.7.0+git~20151231T160311Z~de5bbefdf0~64bit (git de5bbef 2015-12-31 16:03:11Z 64bit).
I use ubuntu 14.04 on intel i5 cpu with 16G ram. 
Sip client used is Zoiper on windows.

Answer (score 1):

You did not tell anything about the codecs that you're using. If you use OPUS in your WebRTC client, and it needs to be transcoded by the FreeSWITCH, then the workload looks quite relevant. OPUS is a quite expensive codec in terms of CPU effort needed for transcoding.

The same applies to the SIP client. The CPU load depends significantly on the codec encoding/decoding job during the call. In ideal situation, both legs of a call use the same codec, and then your FreeSWITCH server would only be busy with sending and receiving RTP frames, without heavy processing of the payload.

Keep in mind that the primary platform for FreeSWITCH is Debian Jessie, and there may also be issues with the kernel or libraries in Ubuntu, as nobody took care to analyze and optimize for this platform.

Comment: Stanislav, thanks a lot for your help! Yes, I use OPUS, does Freeswitch verto supports any other audio codec besides OPUS? Thanks!